# Executing a function after specific images load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have a carousel of low-res .jpeg images that get replaced with larger .gifs after all of the .gifs have loaded (which takes about 10 seconds). The code below replaces all of the .jpeg files with .gifs:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {

$('#carousel-example-generic > .carousel-inner > .item > div[rel]').each(function() {
      var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
      var self = $(this);
      var img = new Image();
      $(img).load(rel, '', function() {
        self.css('background-image', 'url('+rel+')');
      });
    });

});
```

I would like to instead replace each .jpg with its corresponding .gif as soon as that individual .gif is loaded, instead of just waiting for the entire page to load.

The HTML for the individual carousel items looks like this:

```
<div style="background:url('whatever.jpg')" rel="background:url('whatever.gif')"></div>
```

Any advice at how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `window.onload` handler, and use the `onload` handler for each image instead

```
$('#carousel-example-generic > .carousel-inner > .item > div[rel]').each(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var rel  = self.attr('rel');
    var img  = new Image();

    img.onload = function() {
        self.css('background-image', 'url(' + rel + ')');
    }

    img.src = rel;

    if (img.complete) img.onload(); // IE cache "hack"
});
```

and make sure you change the HTML to

```
<div style="background:url('whatever.jpg')" rel="whatever.gif"></div>
```